# Mobile HTML5 Application Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-sql, indexeddb

A quick overview of what I have, and the problems that are associated with it. I have a HTML5 app that I am going to run as a native app using PhoneGap. It is a small data collection application for the local field research station.

The problem with this field station is that they are prone to loosing a signal to transmit data; thus I want to store the data on the device for later use (or to send it to a server).

Data that needs to get saved is the following:

```
*User Name (string)
*Transect Color (string)
*Transect Number (int)
*Transect Board (char)
*Salamander Name (string)
*Snount-Vent Length (int)
*Total Length (int)
*Centipedes (int)
*Red-Black Millipedes (int)
*Brown Round Millipedes (int)
*Brown Flat Millipedes (int)
```

The app itself will be a standalone app, so I want it to have a way to save the data.

What would the best way of doing this be, using a combination of jQuery & HTML5? I know Web SQL is deprecated, but I believe that may be my only way of storing this data. If not, what would be the best way to dynamically store X number of entries before sending?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

How about this situation, when the researcher has to do a "Full Transect"...

The researcher must go from location to location until 20 full data collections on each transect had been done. This entails 20 different locations, each with a varying number of salamanders and critters to be entered.

How would you store that much larger set of data, to be offloaded at the end, when `localstorage` only allows for Key:Value pairs?

Comment: You don't really appear to need the SQL portion of data storage just to store some data. `localStorage` is alive and well, even in IE.

Comment: I'd go `localStorage` too but FWIW it's "wicked slow" in many implementations including Chrome http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a huge fan of wrapping [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) up in a mini key-value store:

```
window.storage = {
  store:localStorage,
  get: function( key ) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(this.store[key]);
    } catch(e) {};
    return undefined;
  },
  set: function( key, value) {
    try {
      this.store[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    } catch(e) {};
  }
}
```

This enables you to reference `window.storage` directly. Assuming you have the fields described wrapped up in a hash called `row`, you can now serialize directly:

```
storage.set('myrow', row);
```

As the data you store in `row` will be serialized, you could create a `document` that contains much more information than a single SQL-row might:

```
var document = {
  property: 'foo',
  nestedArray: [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ],
  nestedObj: { 'key': 'foo', 'key2': 'foo' }
}

storage.set('transectID', document);
```

...you get the idea. The point is that you can even very rich data will be reduced by `JSON.stringify` and saved in a recoverable form.

Comment: Yes. I've updated my explanation with broader treatment of the possibilities for document-based storage (which it sounds like might be a more suitable solution for you here?)

Comment: I am not a javascript ninja but I am sure that `window` is a read-only variable, You cant equal it to an array, gonna edit the answer and change it to something else

Comment: It is not read-only as a scoped local variable (eg. in a function). You should never edit someone else's answer. You can comment or offer a better answer. Maybe contact the author and ask him to improve his answer.

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
var data = {
  name: 'x',
  transect_color: 'red'.
  .....
  ..
};

localStorage.setItem('mydata', JSON.stringify(data));  // mydata is the name of storage
```

And to get the data you can try like following:

```
var temp = localStorage.getItem('mydata');

if(temp != null) {
  var dataJSON = JSON.parse(temp);
}
```

If you want to clear your localStorage data then user following:

```
localStorage.clearItem('mydata');
```

You can store multiple numbers of data like following:

```
var x = [];  // take an array to store all data

x.push({a: 'x', b: 'y'});

localStorage.setItem('mydata', JSON.stringify(x));

// for further entry

var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mydata')); // retrieve localStroage item

temp.push({a: 'xx', b: 'yy'})  // push new data to array

localStorage.setItem('mydata', JSON.stringify(t)); // overwrite the existing entry with new data

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))); // you will see your all data here
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to store large data sets in `localStorage`.

**WebSQL is deprecated**. [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) is the tool of choice for larger in-browser data sets but is not yet available in PhoneGap (though it's supposedly on the road map).

Counter-intuitively, even though WebSQL spec will not be developed further [WebSQL is still the most widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=websql) option out there, whereas IndexedDB is still very nascent.

If you go the localStore route, as with mobile you should trust the in-memory representation whenever possible and only read from "disk" when you can't from memory.