# How can I make a search box to search in a local database?

Tags: javascript, database, search, cordova, local

I'm playing around with **Apache Cordova** and I want to implement a search box that can search in a list or something similar (local database?). I want it to be local so that the app does not require an internet connection to search.

The way I want it to be set up is that it need to be able to search for both the name of the item and a number.

---

### Example 1:

> A user searches for: "Honda". He will then be sent to a page where information about "Honda" will be diplayed.

### Example 2:

> A user searches for the id: "1337". He will then be sent to the page containing information about "Honda".

So "Honda = 1337" and "1337 = Honda" if you guys understand?

---

### The question:

I'm wondering what solution would suite my needs for this project? 
or there any frameworks out there for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have that much of experience in app designing but I am answering this question on the basis of my experience in web development. 
You question seems somewhat weird. You want to do all the operations locally. How you are supposed to maintain a DB locally.Even if you can you should not store large amount of values in it. The DB size can be large.
Imagine your Facebook app stores all the data you have locally on your phone memory. No matter how much compressed DB you have.You will still acquire lot amount of memory.

Comment: What you say makes a lot of sense! Although, how can i achieve searching locally then?

Comment: Since Mobile browsers support HTML 5 now a days. We can take benefit of appcache. Using AppCache you can cache your HTML pages. But if you don't have a HTML 5 App. Then I would suggest taking a look at 

For App Based Local Storage:
http://devcenter.appery.io/tutorials/building-hello-world-app-with-html5-local-storage/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442211/mobile-html5-application-local-storage

For HTML 5 based local storage options:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to have the search box and submit to be like.

One way is to use this really great tool http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ it can load data from database (using either ajax or load all of your data and only filter them) and shows them in selectbox. You can have submit button or something like that next to your selectbox.

Other way might be to use http://www.datatables.net/ it has search box, which can load data to table using ajax where you can have additional information and submit button for sending user to specific page.

There is plenty of other tools for this kind of problem, I used these two and I can say

Comment: Took a fast look over both of them. Will say that "datatables" looks more like it suites my needs except that i would like not to show the table of all the content. 

Do you think its possible to have a blank page just with an search box then when you hit "search" you will be "redirected" to the results? instead of watching all of them? :)

Comment: I'd say add event listener to search box and when it is empty either slide down or hide (or whatever animation you want) to table content. So basically you can load data continuously while user input some query and show the table once some criteria is met. Like say we want to show the table only if user puts 4 characters in search box. If you want just blank page and search box I'd suggest moving the search box of datable to some location on page and creating function for hiding/sliding table content. But this is just my quick suggestion I am certain you can think of something more elegant.